# Setup project not able to overwrite existing font file with a new one with the same name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, fonts, setup-project

I have a Setup project in C# in which I have added a font file "CustomizedFont.ttf" in Fonts folder. It works fine and installs "CustomizedFont.ttf" on the system when the same is not present already. But when the same name font file is already present, setup is not able to overwrite already existent font file with new font file.

PS: Replacing is necessary because I have made some changes in font file with the same name. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Excellent: that should not be a thing you can just do without administrator permissions. Are you making sure you've obtained UAC permissions for that operation? Also, why does your font need to be in the fonts folder? If it's only used by your application, just have it live in the application's folder and load it from there. Don't system-install it unless it's a "regular" font that comes as part of your application bundle, and people are free to use outside your application.

Answer (score 0):

After ensuring that there are enough  UAC permissions, I have used versioning of fonts file for the same. So now, if the font is already installed then new version will be installed. After doing this it works fine.